# Using a service to handle multiple intents

Tags: android, service

I wanted to create a service such that it could keep being launched from the activity with different arguments, and whenever any of the argument conditions is true, it would show notification specific to that argument.

Like if I want the phone to notify me when I'm at a specified location, and i can give multiple such location values, such that if I'm at any of those locations it should tell me and when any one location is reached it should not stop all the other threads checking for the other locations.

I didn't explain it very well, but Im getting confused on this.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really how services are designed. What you are looking for sounds much more like at [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html). Using one of these, a single server can send and receive multiple notifications for different situations. Running several services in this case sounds wasteful.

Comment: Can't I make multiple threads as and when the service is called? I'm not familiar with Broadcast receivers and so am unsure how they handle it.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to suggest not to do a service. Your question seemed to suggest to me you were thinking of running multiple services to do similar things. You should have *a* service. Your service can have multiple threads. If you are looking to send notifications back, the broadcast receiver will help you a lot. Maybe explain **what** you envision each thread doing, so I can offer more help.

Comment: Basically, I have an app where you specify the location of a place, and when you are near that location it alerts you. I was thinking of passing the latitude and longitude to a service, which would use the addproximityalert method and give an alert when near the place. I just want it to be such that I can give multiple places. Sadly the thread/service/broadcast thing is confusing me.

Comment: Does the user add additional locations from the activity?

Comment: Yes. He can open the app at any time and specify another additional location.

Comment: Then I think its a great idea to have a single persistent service.  The Activity can connect to the service using the local service mechanism described [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#LocalServiceSample). The issue is communicating in the other direction, from service to Activity. This is where I would recommend a broadcast receiver. This allows you to asynchronously communicate to the activity if it is open (and you can use sticky broadcasts so later opens get messages too). Finally, post a status to the notification area using a notification manager.

Comment: Oh, so in this case, even if the application itself is closed the service is still bound to it? As in when it opens again, assuming the service hasn't been destroyed, it will be able to communicate with it? There was one more thing...do you have any idea how I could create the threads in the service so that each services a different location request? I mean, each lonitude/latitude passed has to have an individual addproximityalert and a seperate locationManager right? Do i have to create each thread with a different identifier name, or something? :( I'm new to java :(

Comment: Create an object to contain your thread logic whose constructor takes a lat long pair. Then in the service, you should use an ExecutorService and submit the Runnables to that service for execution.

Answer (score 0):

It will help if you can be more clear about your question.  If it is about proximity alert, you might get help by looking at Reto's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113606/does-anyone-know-whether-the-android-addproximityalert-on-the-locationmanager-is).  If it is about creating a service that Android will launch to handle any of a class of Intents, processing them appropriately based upon a specific argument (such as Action), then [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3298388/set-2-proximity-alerts-with-the-same-broadcast) might be closer to what you are looking for.